# Magento 2: How to Load Customer collections in admin panel by Using Plugin

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, plugin, customer-collection

I am using plugin to load the customer collection in admin panel,this is i have done..

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/
config.xsd">


    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <plugin name="productdata" type="Learning\HelloPage\Plugin\ProductDataProvider" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Here is my plugin file `Plugin/CustomerDataProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Plugin;

class CustomerDataProvider
{
       public function aroundGetData(
        \Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) 
    {   

        //what to do here??

    }


}
```

as customer page keeps loading all the time..
here is a screenshot..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this article - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Your mistake in this case that you forgot to call `callable` function.

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Plugin;

class CustomerDataProvider
{
       public function aroundGetData(
        \Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) 
    {   

        $proceed();

    }


}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function setPageSize() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

Comment: got this if i use proceed();